# Why can't millimeter waves travel far

Tags: wave

So I was digging around 5g technology, and apparently, many people say that high-band 5g can't penetrate buildings, trees, even rain. However, the atmospheric attenuation around 30 GHz does not seem to be a lot (eyeballing gives me 0.15 dB/km):

[image]

So my question is, why can't high-band 5g travel far? Are there attenuation graphs that engineers designing 5g use that's more comprehensive?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a signal processing, but a propagation physics question. Also, hint: Free Space Path Loss.

Comment: Having worked with 60 GHz in detail I could provide an answer but agree with Marcus and happy to answer there if you migrate this question

Comment: Presumably that's for dry air.  You need plots for rain, snow, through trees & walls, etc.

Comment: physics.stackexchange.com would be a good place I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lossy mediums, the attenuation actually is a function of frequency and it typically increases as the increment of the frequency. I recommend you to take a look at the Maxwell Equations.
The magnitude of electromagnetic waves exponentially decreases $(e^{-\alpha x})$ as the travel distance increases. To give an intuition, in lossy mediums (a lossy cable, waveguide, any kind of non-ideal material), $\alpha$ can be written as $ \alpha=\omega \sqrt{\mu \varepsilon}\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\omega^{2} \varepsilon^{2}}}\right]^{1 / 2}$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the medium, $\epsilon$ is the dielectric constant, $\mu$ is the magnetic permeability, and $\omega = 2\pi f$ is the angular frequency. As you can see, this basic identity shows that the attenuation of a medium is dependent on the frequency of the electromagnetic waves. It holds for wireless mediums (with some improvements on the expression) as well.